# Why does my stored procedure doesn't set value to variable?

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures

I've altered an stored procedure I made with MySQL, I've declared two new variables and then setting them a value from a select command, but it's not getting any value from the select command, I tried running the same select statement outside the stored procedure and it works fine there. Why could the select command not work properly inside the stored procedure?

This is the piece of the sp that is not working properly:

```
DECLARE reorden INT;
DECLARE minimo INT;
...
...
IF (existenciasresta>=0) THEN
SELECT REORDEN FROM productos WHERE ID_PRODUCTO =id INTO reorden;
SELECT MINIMO FROM productos WHERE ID_PRODUCTO = id INTO minimo;
IF (existenciasresta<reorden) THEN
    SELECT 'El producto está en su punto de reorden';
ELSEIF (existenciasresta<minimo) THEN
    SELECT 'El producto está en su punto mínimo';
END IF;
SET retorno = 1;
```

The variables reorden and minimo are set to null after running the sp, when I run this statement in the query tab I get the correct value:

```
 SELECT REORDEN FROM productos WHERE ID_PRODUCTO = '1233333333333';
```

It's correctly passing the if condition since it's correctly setting retorno to 1, so I really don't know why is behaving like this, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I already solved the problem, just by changing the columns names, couldn't figure out why but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write `INTO` keyword after column name which column value put into the `varible`
Try This query instead of your `select query`

```
SELECT REORDEN INTO reorden FROM productos WHERE ID_PRODUCTO =id ;
SELECT MINIMO INTO minimo FROM productos WHERE ID_PRODUCTO = id ;
```

OR

```
SET reorden = (SELECT REORDEN FROM productos WHERE ID_PRODUCTO =id);
SET minimo = (SELECT MINIMO FROM productos WHERE ID_PRODUCTO = id) ;
```

both is the right query which you want you can use.

Comment: No, that didn't work, actually my problem is not a syntax error since I've used the INTO clause before without any problem. The problem is that the select statement is not getting any resultset when running inside the sp, I know it because I made some tests already and got null values.

Comment: what is the type of REORDEN and MINIMO  in table ?

Comment: They're both int(10)

Comment: how did you check it is null ?

Comment: did you check your if else condition write in sp ? because as i seen you start two `if condition` but you end only one `if`

Comment: Thanks, I already solved the problem, just by changing the columns names, still don't know why it didn't work before, maybe MySQL just didn't like the names I gave them before, but anyway I'm glad I could work it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've found similar strange behavior. Given the procedure below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_product_family(IN name VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE name1 VARCHAR(10);
    SET name1 = name;
    DELETE FROM product_family WHERE name = name1;
END
```

I found I have to change it to the following for it to work as expected.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_product_family(IN myname VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM product_family WHERE name = myname;
END
```